# excluding properties from Identity.EntityFrameworkIdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim>

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have the following class

```
public class AppUser : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser<int, AppLogin, AppUserRole, AppClaim>
{
    public AppUser()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastActivityDate { get; set; }
}
```

From the base class i don't want to send to the database some values like "`TwoFactorEnabled`", "`PhoneNumberConfirmed`", etc.

But I can't exclude then from the database because the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext` doesn't allow me to override the `OnModelCreating`.

So, how can I exclude this properties from my `dbcontext`?

Comment: You can implement `IUser<int>` instead of deriving from `IdentityUser`. Then you can customize as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my self the answer. The IdentityDbContext class has a protected method called OnModelCreating (like the DbContext class). There i manage to exclude the values that I wanted